# Empty S3 buckets from a given list variable using boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to use boto3 to list how many objects have all of my buckets that I put into a list, once I know the number of objects in each bucket form the list I want to delete all of the objects inside to have all buckets in 0.

This is my snippet:

```
    import boto3
    import botocore
    
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    # Using this paginator I can see all of the objects in the bucket
    paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    
    def s3_list_delete():
        bucket_list = [
            'bucket-1',
            'bucket-2',
            'bucket-3'
        ]
    
    for bucket in bucket_list:
        count = 0
        for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket):
            count += page['KeyCount']
        print(f'In the S3 Bucket "{bucket}" there are "{count}" number of objects')
    obj_delete=str(input('Want to empty all of the Buckets? Type Y to confirm: '))
    if obj_delete == 'Y':
        for objs in bucket.objects.all():
            objs.delete()
            print('Objects have been deleted')
    else:
        return False


s3_list_delete()
```

The only output I have is the number of objects each bucket have, and after pressing Y just nothing.

I think the question here is how can I iterate over the objects of each bucket of my S3 List, like to empty the objects in first bucket of the bucket_list[0] and so on...

Comment: Ask yourself what `bucket` is when you execute`for objs in bucket.objects.all()`.

Comment: Your deletion code should (presumably) be _indented_ within the `for bucket in bucket_list:` loop. Also, when using `bucket.objects.all()`, the `bucket` variable should be a **bucket object** (eg `Object(bucket)`) rather than a string with the **name** of the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3') 


bucket_list = []

def emptyBucket(bucket_list):
    for bucket in bucket_list:
        count = 0
        print(bucket)
        for object in s3.Bucket(bucket):
            print(object.key)
            object.delete()
            count +=1
        print(bucket,'-', count) 
        
        
emptyBucket(bucket_list)
```

This code makes empty all buckets that are in the "bucket_list".
It print the name of all objects and the number of objects